# Slim фрэймворк, как работает промежуточное ПО

Tags: php, slim, slim4

Я не совсем понимаю концепции промежуточного ПО, в частности в Slim фреймворк. Вот пример из документации:

```
$beforeMiddleware = function (Request $request, RequestHandler $handler) {
    $response = $handler->handle($request);
    $existingContent = (string) $response->getBody();

    $response = new Response();
    $response->getBody()->write('BEFORE' . $existingContent);

    return $response;
};

$afterMiddleware = function ($request, $handler) {
    $response = $handler->handle($request);
    $response->getBody()->write('AFTER');
    return $response;
};

$app->add($beforeMiddleware);
$app->add($afterMiddleware);

// ...

$app->run();
```

Почему beforeMiddleware выполнится до обработки роута (до вызова контроллера на который указывает маршрут), а afterMiddleware после.

и что происходит при вызове

```
$response = $handler->handle($request);
```

И дополнительный вопрос: когда во всем этом контексте нужно использовать Response и Request Factory из PSR-17 и нужно ли это вообще?

Заранее спасибо за ответ и прошу прощение если вопрос поставлен не точно или не корректно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Почему beforeMiddleware выполнится до обработки роута (до вызова контроллера на который указывает маршрут), а afterMiddleware после.

На самом деле, `beforeMiddleware` и `afterMiddleware` начнут выполнять свою работу до вызова контроллера.

```
$app->add($beforeMiddleware);
$app->add($afterMiddleware);
```

Здесь Вы указываете приложению порядок миддлварей. В `slim` они будут обрабатываться в обратном порядке, т.е. сначала `afterMiddleware`, потом `beforeMiddleware`.

в `afterMiddleware` slim передаст первым параметром объект запроса, а вторым параметром обертку, вызывающую следующий миддлварь (`beforeMiddleware`). В последний миддлварь в качестве обработчика передастся обработчик контроллера.

```
// afterMiddleware
$afterMiddleware = function ($request, $handler) {
    // Сначала мы получаем ответ приложения
    // (т.е. тут сработает и beforeMiddleware, и контроллер)
    $response = $handler->handle($request);
    // Теперь к телу ответа допишется 'AFTER'
    $response->getBody()->write('AFTER');
    // И этот ответ вернётся
    return $response;
};

$beforeMiddleware = function (Request $request, RequestHandler $handler) {
    // Получаем ответ от контроллера (или следующего миддлваря)
    $response = $handler->handle($request);
    // Получаем строку тела ответа
    $existingContent = (string) $response->getBody();
    // Создаём новый ответ
    // Не забывайте, что создавая новый объект ответа,
    // вы можете потерять заголовки, добавленные в контроллере
    $response = new Response();
    // Записываем в тело нового ответа тело 
    // полученного ответа с префиксом 'BEFORE'
    $response->getBody()->write('BEFORE' . $existingContent);
    // Возвращаем новый ответ
    return $response;
};
```

Вообще, можно было обойтись одним миддлварем:

```
$middleware = function (Request $request, RequestHandler $handler) {
    // Здесь выполняется всё, что нужно выполнить ДО вызова контроллера


    $content = 'BEFORE';

    // Получаем ответ от контроллера (или следующего миддлваря)
    $response = $handler->handle($request);

    // Здесь выполняем всё, что нужно выполнить ПОСЛЕ вызова контроллера

    $body = $response->getBody();
    // Дописываем содержимое ответа контроллера
    $content .= $body->getContents();
    // Дописываем 'BEFORE'
    $content .= 'BEFORE';

    // Перемещаем курсор тела в начало
    $body->rewind();
    // Записываем новое содержимое тела ответа
    $body->write($content);

    // Возвращаем ответ
    return $response;
};
```

ResponseFactory и RequestFactory из PSR-17 необходимо использовать только там, где вы заведомо не знаете, какая именно реализация PSR-7 используется.

Например, вы пишете библиотеку, которая вернет `ResponseInterface`, но не знаете, что именно будут использовать пользователи. Тогда вы можете попросить передать вам пустой объект ответа, который ваш код заполнит, либо (что более правильно) `ResponseFactory`, из которого ваш код построит объект ответа.